# handling ajax and jquery in django template

Tags: django, jquery, django-templates

I am trying to load page in two parts. 
second part is only render when user click on 'show more details'

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle_details').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('up')){
            $(this).removeClass('up').addClass('down');
            $('#toggle_text').html('Show More Details');
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('down').addClass('up');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'some_url_returning_json',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $( '.name' ).html(data.name);
                    $( '.lname' ).html(data.lname);
                    alert(data.name);
                }
            })
            $('#toggle_text').html('Hide Details');
        }
        $('#details').slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
    $('#details').hide();
});    
</script>
```

and my html is :

```
<div class="ad-grp-tbl creative-tbl custom-tbl">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Status:</th>

            <td id='status'>{{ status }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="100%" id="details">
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <td id="name" >{{data.name}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Last Name:</th>
            <td id ="lname">{{ data.lname}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="tog">
                <span id="toggle_text" style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">Show More Details</span>
                <span class="down" id="toggle_details"></span>
            </th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

So Basically I am not able to load the json return value in the template.
hw can i fix it. or my approach for solving the problem is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You have missed out ';' semi-colon for ajax method

Answer (score 1):

I show you an example:

```
def post_ajax(request):
    TOTLE = 5
    OFFSET = int(request.GET.get('offset', 0))
    END = OFFSET + TOTLE

    if OFFSET + 1 >= Post.objects.count():
        LOADED = "已经全部加载完毕"
        return HttpResponse(LOADED)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(pub_time__lte=timezone.now())[OFFSET:END]

    json_list = []
    for post in posts:
        t = get_template('blog/ajax_post.html')
        html = t.render(Context({'post': post}))
        # print(html)
        json_list.append({
            'html': html,
        })
    data = json.dumps(json_list)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

Is this you need?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax + JQuery will get response and should put data appropriately in the page. Template of original page doesn't have much role to play.

However, you have to implement separate url+view+template that will handle the ajax request. You can use existing view but need to handle for ajax request (i.e. just to send part of html, likely using another template).

The template for ajax response should send only the relevant part of html and not the entire html page.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML you have ids set but you are using the class selector.

It should be:

```
$( '#name' ).html(data.name);
$( '#lname' ).html(data.lname);
```

instead of:

```
$( '.name' ).html(data.name);
$( '.lname' ).html(data.lname);
```

`.` is the class selector and `#` is the id selector.

You can try using Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to see that the above returns the items.